# How to fix the Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found error in Vue + Node?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I'm build a a web app that takes in speech and converts into text. The text is then converted into text and sent to openai(chatgpt) so that it returns the answer. aws polly is what i use for the voice ouptu when chatgpt returns an answer.

My problem is that i am getting the following error in my vue app in production:

```
/voice/66154949.mp3:1     GET https://jarvis-ruby-rho.vercel.app/voice/66154949.mp3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

The code works fine locally, but i am getting that error in production(vercel and netlify)

Heres my Node(express) code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const fs = require("fs");
const dotenv = require("dotenv")

dotenv.config()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const configuration = new Configuration({ apiKey: process.env.OPEN_AI_KEY});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.loadFromPath("AWS_Credentials.json");

app.post('/api/TTS', async (req, res) => {

    const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: req.body.text,
        max_tokens: 100,
        temperature: 0.5
    })
    console.log(completion)

    let num = (Math.random() * 100000000).toFixed(0);

    const awsPolly = new AWS.Polly({ region: "us-east-1" })
    const params = {
        OutputFormat: "mp3",
        Text: completion.data.choices[0].text,
        VoiceId: "Matthew"
    }

    awsPolly.synthesizeSpeech(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        let filePath = "../public/voice/";
        let fileName = num + ".mp3";

        if (num) fs.writeFileSync(filePath + fileName, data.AudioStream)
    })

    setTimeout(() => { res.status(200).json(num) }, 4500)
})

app.listen(PORT, () => { 
    console.log(`Listening at ${PORT}`); 
});
```

my vue code:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useAVLine } from 'vue-audio-visual';

const player = ref(null);
const canvas = ref(null);
let mySource = ref(null);
let action = ref('');
let output = ref('');

useAVLine(player, canvas, { src: mySource, canvHeight: 300, canvWidth: 1000, lineColor: 'orange' });

const runSpeechRecognition = () => {
  var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
  var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

  recognition.onstart = () => {
    action.value = "I'm Listening";
  };

  recognition.onspeechend = () => {
    action.value = 'Done';
    recognition.stop();
  };

  recognition.onresult = async (event) => {
    var transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;
    output.value = transcript;

    try {
      const baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:3001'
      const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/api/TTS`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          text: event.results[0][0].transcript,
        }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data)
        if (data) {
          mySource.value = `${import.meta.env.BASE_URL}voice/${data}.mp3`;
          setTimeout(() => {
            player.value.play();
          }, 500);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Request failed with status:', response.status);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  recognition.start();
};
</script>

<template>
  <div class="show">
    <div class="action" v-if="action">{{ action }}</div>
    <div class="synthesizedSpeech" v-if="output"><b>Question</b>: {{ output }}</div>
  </div>

  <div class="audio-wrapper">
    <audio id="player" ref="player" :src="mySource" type="audio/mp3" controls hidden></audio>
    <canvas ref="canvas" />
    <div class="button-section">
    <button type="button" @click="runSpeechRecognition()">Ask Me Anything</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
body {
  background-color: rgb(23, 23, 23);
}

.audio-wrapper{
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
}

.button-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

button {
  padding: 8px 13px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.action {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.synthesizedSpeech {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #313131;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

P.S: i have my backend folder(code) inside my root vue code( my backend folder is nested where inside the frontend)

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the audio tag properly

```
<audio  ... >
   <source :src="mySource" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

use 'source' tag instead of using 'src' property, which should be URL type.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_src.asp